# Exporting the names of all custom voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: export, dragon-naturally-speaking

How can I export the names of all the voice commands I have defined in Dragon NaturallySpeaking?

I don't want to explore the voice commands themselves (which can be done following [these instructions](http://nuance.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5719/~/importing-and-exporting-commands-in-the-command-browser)), but just the list of their names.

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native function in Dragon that allows you to export the command names.

One way is to export all your custom commands as XML:

When in the dialogue where you export the commands, select XML instead of dat as file type.

Open the XML file in an editor or in Excel and filter for the names.

Another  is to use an add-on to Dragon, SayWhatPro, that would allow you to do what you want (http://www.speechutilities.com/SayWhatPro/index.htm, not affiliated).